# Let $f,g\in V^*$ and assume $g \neq 0$. Show that $f= ag$ for some $a \in F$ iff $Ker(g) \subseteq Ker(f)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f,g\in V^*$ and assume $g \neq 0$. Show that $f= ag$ for some $a \in F$ iff $Ker(g) \subseteq Ker(f)$.

One direction is easy.
for other direction Suppose $Ker(g) \subseteq Ker(f)$.
 Now $rk(f)+null(f)=dim V$ and $rk(g)+null(g)=dim V$. Still from this eqn I am not getting any clue. So how to proceed from here?

Comment: What is $V^*$? I am not familiar with this.

Comment: Dual space of $V$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $g \neq 0$, there is an $x_0 \in V$ such that $g(x_0)=1$.  Now, $x-g(x)x_0$ is in kernel $g$ (for all $x \in V$). Since $\ker (g) \subset \ker (f)$, $f(x-g(x)x_0)=0$, hence $f(x)=g(x)f(x_0)$. Let $a=f(x_0)$.

The converse is obvious.

Note that $g \neq 0$ implies that $g$ is onto, since $\mathbb{C}$ is one dimensional.

Comment: Neat proof! This also works in infinite-dimensional spaces.